# Set object or button above the video in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

In my application i want to set background video playing on the screen.how to set images and buttons above the video.

Answer (score -1):

I see two solutions for your problem :

1/ Using different display groups and toFront

```
videoDisplayGroup = display.newGroup();
buttonsDisplayGroup = display.newGroup();

function setupScreen()
    videoDisplayGroup:toFront(); 
    buttonsDisplayGroup(); 
end
```

You just add the buttons and the video in the corresponding display group.

2/ Using an overlay

Check this http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/showOverlay.html

Comment: native video object cannot added into group then how it is possible.